# Connecting to Hive Metastore ( with Kerberos authentication) with Pyspark on Windows

Tags: python, apache-spark, hive, pyspark, kerberos

I'm trying to connect to a Hive database with Kerberos authentication using Pyspark in Windows 10.  So far I've done the following:

(1) Set environment variables:
   SPARK_HOME = C:\spark
   HADOOP_HOME = C:\spark\hadoop
   Added C:\spark\bin to the PATH variables
   MAVEN_HOME = C:\apache-maven-3.3.9

(2) Saved the hive-site.xml file in C:\spark\conf

(3) Downloaded binaries (https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils/tree/master/hadoop-2.7.1)  for the version of hadoop used by spark (hadoop 2.7) and I saved these files in HADOOP_HOME\bin

(4) I ran the following command: winutils.exe -R 777 C:\tmp\hive

(5)  I run the kinit command to get a Kerberos ticket.  Then I run:

```
from pyspark import SparkCOntext, SparkConf
sparkSession =SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
d_load = sparkSession.sql("select count(*) from table")
```

After running this I get errors saying:

"...

```
Caused by: GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any kerberos tgt)
at sun.security.jss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getCredentialElement(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getMechanismContext( Unknown Source)
at sun.security.jss.GSSManagerImpl.getMechanismContext( Unknown Source)
at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext( Unknown Source)
at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext( Unknown Source)
...67 more
18/10/20 22:35:25 WARN metastore: Failed to connect to the Metastore Server...
Traceback (most recent call):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\spark\python\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 710, in sql
return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self_wrapped)
File "C:\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
File "C:\spark\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py, line 69, in deco
raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'java.lang.RUnTimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetastoreClient;
```

- Can you please help me try to figure out why I get this error? Is there a way that I can make sure that pyspark is reading the hive-site.xml file?  I read that I might also need to add a variable for **KRB5_KTNAME** but I don't have a keytab file anywhere--does anyone know how may I set this up?
- Also, I read in a thread that I had to save binaries in the SPARK_HOME\bin folder as well (in addition to HADOOP_HOME), but they are the same as the files that I downloaded and saved in HADOOP_HOME\bin.  What is the right thing to do here?  What are the binaries/winutils.exe files that go in HADOOP_HOME\bin and the ones that go in SPARK_HOME\bin?  (I've read conflicting versions of this.)

Thanks so much for your help!!

Comment: https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/72103/alternate-days-why-do-i-see-gssexception-no-valid.html

Comment: Any warning about missing "native libraries"? Since you did not add the path to Hadoop DLLs in the PATH, I would bet the Hadoop auth lib derails and you get a nondescript error message.

Comment: For Windows tweaks, find the GitBook by Jacek Laskowski "Mastering Apache Spark 2" and go straight to "Running Spark apps on Windows". I could do some nit-picking about using HADOOP_HOME and PATH instead of -Dhadoop.home and -Djava.library.path but his advice just works.

Comment: Hi @Prazy, thanks for sending me the link.  This is really helpful. It looks like I need to get the key tab file, then find the Kerberos Principal name and run a kinit on this principal name. I'll do this as soon as I retrieve this file.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter I'm sorry forgot to mention in my question that I saved those files in HADOOP_HOME\bin!  The files with dll extension are: snappy.dll, lzo2.dll, hdfs.dll, hadoop.dll, and gplcompression.dll and HADOOP_HOME\lib\native, and a few others.  The HADOOP_HOME\bin is the one where I included the yarn.cmd and other files that are also the SPARK_HOME\bin.  Still when I run 'pyspark' in the command prompt I see "WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform...using-java classes where applicable".  Are these the dll's that you referred to?

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter I just read "Running Spark apps on Windows" --I'll try setting this up from the beginning and hopefully once I get the Key tab file the errors will go away. Thank you for suggesting the book!